# Как получать города из СДЭК и подставлять в select?

Tags: python, платежи

У СДЭК API есть метод, который возвращает все города из их базы. Но проблема в том, что они как-то очень криво берутся.
Ибо там есть всякие деревни и поселки, но нет крупных городов (даже таких как Москва, СПБ, Волгоград и тд), это очень странно.
Я подумал сначала брать города другим методом, не из API СДЭК, однако позже обнаружил, что для работы с другими методами, например создания заказа, требуется id города в их базе, то есть мне наверняка придется брать оттуда.
Вопрос как это делать, если их апи отдает города таким неподходящим образом?
Возможно у них какой то другой метод (я использовал пункт 4.13 из их документации ([Список городов](https://confluence.cdek.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15616129))) Или возможно брать города из другого сервиса и как то подставлять их?

```py
response = requests.get('http://integration.cdek.ru/v1/location/cities/json?countryId=RU').json()
cities = [city_data['cityName'] for city_data in response]
print(cities)  # здесь поселки и тд, без крупных городов
```

Comment: `size Ограничение выборки результата. По умолчанию 1000 `.Там в 4.13.1 есть ссылка на zip архив базы СДЭК.

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324059/%d0%9c%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%9c%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2] (Михаил), Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Возможно помогу кому то этим.
Искал способы получения информации о пунктах сдек по АПИ без лога.
В результате

- библиотека fs-cdek-api - по логу
- pycdek и pycdek3 - не работают без лога, ошибка аля (метода не существует), лезть в исходники и тратить время не стал
- официальное API CDEK по post/get запросам. V2 - требует лог пароль даже для получения пунктов

Что и итоге сработало без лога.
Запрос по v1 как в описании, но, либо параметры на время написания этого вопроса автором были другие, либо он подставлял не верный параметр. Подробно [смотрите на оф. документации](https://confluence.cdek.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15616129#id-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8(v1.5)-4.1.PVZ%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%9F%D0%92%D0%97) про параметры.
[image: актуальные параметры для получения списка городов]

В моем случае хватило запроса
http://integration.cdek.ru/pvzlist/v1/xml?citypostcode=603000

Если задача такая же как у автора темы, "найти города", то в инструкции на то так же есть запрос. По поводу получения всех городов РФ, достаточно указать запрос

http://integration.cdek.ru/v1/location/cities/json?countryCode=RU

Answer (score 0):

Идентификатор города в базе СДЭКа умеет отдавать сервис dadata - https://dadata.ru/api/delivery/